# Nested ManytoMany field not in the Response

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to write a nested serializer which would add serialize 2 models in the same view. Serialization seems to work fine since changes get reflected in the database but I am not able to get the many-to-many related field data in the response. I have been trying to figure out what the issue might be but still no progress.
Here is my code:

**Model**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    AccountName = models.ManyToManyField(Account,
                                         through='User_Account',
                                         through_fields=('user', 'acc'),
                                         related_name='AccountData',
                                         blank=True)

    EmailId = models.EmailField(max_length=128, blank=False, null=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'EmailId'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['AccountName']
```

```
class Account(models.Model):
    AccountName = models.TextField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
```

**Serializer**

```
class AccountCreationSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ["AccountName"]

class SignUpSerializer1(ModelSerializer):
    AccountData = AccountCreationSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['EmailId', 'AccountData', 'password']
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'required': True}}

    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super(SignUpSerializer1, self).validate(attrs=attrs)
        attrs.update({"AccountData": self.initial_data.get("AccountData")})
        return attrs

    def create(self, validated_data):
        AccountName_data = validated_data.pop('AccountData')
        acc = Account.objects.create(AccountName=AccountName_data)
        userAcc = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        if acc:
            userAcc.AccountName.add(acc)
            print("added")
        return userAcc
```

**View**

```
class SignUpView(APIView):
    serializer_class1 = SignUpSerializer1

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        if request.data['CreateAccount']:
            serializer = self.serializer_class1(data=request.data)
            is_valid_serializer = serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            if is_valid_serializer:
                with transaction.atomic():
                    serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        else:
            raise Exception("Bad error")
```

**Request1**

```
    "EmailId" : "xyz@gmail.com",
    "AccountData":{"AccountName":"TestAcc1"},
    "CreateAccount": true,
    "password" : "xyz"
```

**Response**

```
    "EmailId": "xyz@gmail.com",
```

#After Removing read_only=true from AccountData

**Request2**

```
    "EmailId" : "xyz@gmail.com",
    "AccountData":{"AccountName":"TestAcc1"},
    "CreateAccount": true,
    "password" : "xyz"
```

**Response**

```
    {"AccountData":{"non_field_errors":["Expected a list of items but got type \"dict\"."]}}
```

**Request3**

```
    "EmailId" : "xyz@gmail.com",
    "AccountData":[{"AccountName":"TestAcc1"}],
    "CreateAccount": true,
    "password" : "xyz"
```

**Response**

```
 Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `AccountData` on serializer `SignUpSerializer1`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `User` instance.
Original exception text was: 'User' object has no attribute 'AccountData'.
```

There is no response data fo AccountName in the response. And when I try `print(User.objects.get(EmailId = serializer.data['AccountName'])) ====> None`.

 How should I get the field populated in the correct way in my response?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you follow correctly this example in the documentation : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers ?

Comment: @Benbb96 Yes I am referring to the documentation for nested relation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `source` argument, since model's field called `AccountName`, not `AccountData`:

```
class SignUpSerializer1(ModelSerializer):
    AccountData = AccountCreationSerializer(many=True, source="AccountName")
```